# Is there a way to configure an Azure VM where the OS is on an SSD?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I've taken a look at the D-series size which gives you an SSD.  However it is a temporary disk and from running some benchmarks in my VM, the OS disk seems to be on spinning metal.

Has anyone tried a setup where the OS itself is installed on an SSD?  I'd like to build a development environment that I can remote to from anywhere, but it's very slow and task manager shows me the culprit is being disk-bound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use any VM family that supports **Premium Storage**.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-premium-storage/

> **Premium Storage** supports VM disks that can be attached to specific size-series VMs. Premium Storage supports **DS-series, DSv2-series, GS-series, and Fs-series VMs**. You have a choice of three disk sizes: P10 (128 GB), P20 (512 GB), and P30 (1,024 GB). Each disk size has its own performance specifications. Depending on your application requirements, you can attach one or more disks to your VM. We describe the specifications in more detail in [Premium Storage scalability and performance targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-premium-storage#premium-storage-scalability-and-performance-targets).
>
> **Operating System Disk:** You can set up your Premium Storage VM to use either a premium or a standard operating system disk. For the best experience, we recommend using a Premium Storage-based operating system disk.

Looks like they've made things caveman simple now:

[image: SSD]

Comment: Thanks, I was reusing an old vm image and couldn't find a way to switch from HDD to SSD.  Created a new VM and I'm flying now.